# IE 11 coming up as Mozilla in Google Analytics

Tags: internet-explorer, google-analytics, internet-explorer-11

I am looking at my sites data in Google Analytics and notice under browser version that no data appears under internet explorer v11.  But if I look at Mozilla that is getting data for v 11.  It seems as though all IE 11 data is coming through under Mozilla rather than Internet Explorer.  Is there anything that can be done as a user here or do we just have to wait for Google to adjust?

Comment: This is actually pretty funny, especially considering how long the IE11 user agent string changes have been publicly known now.

Comment: yeah they are trying to bust all the stupid browser sniffing out there and in Google's normal MO they are intentionally not making things work in IE. The User Agent change has been known for months, they could have adjusted accordingly by now.

Comment: I bet Microsoft "stole" all of Firefox's source code and forgot to change the user agent string. :) Seriously, though, the only thing I would do is click "Send feedback" on Google Analytics footer (in the stats view). Or, try and contact a Google web dev. If IE is appearing as Firefox for you only, see if you are spoofing the user agent in the F12 dev tools under emulation (Ctrl + 8).

Comment: Good news. This appears to have been fixed in Google Analytics as of Wednesday 18th December.

Comment: @coliff You should create an answer from your comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed in Google Analytics as of Wednesday 18th December 2013.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, There is no API to specify the user agent in the client SDKs for Android, IOS and web.

To work around this for now, You could detect the browser and use a [custom dimension](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/analyticsjs/custom-dims-mets) to track IE11 usage.

Simply use:

```
// Code to detect IE11
if (isIE11) {
  ga('set', 'dimension1':  'IE11');
}
```