# Google Analytics differentiating Mozilla and firefox browsers

Tags: firefox, google-analytics

I am looking at my sites data in Google Analytics and notice under browser version that there access with Mozilla and Firefox. But wasn't it Mozilla and Firefox the same browsers? [At this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20184589/ie-11-coming-up-as-mozilla-in-google-analytics) question, the op suggests that IE 11 access could appear as Mozilla. Is that always the case?

Comment: There was a ["Mozilla Browser"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mozilla_Application_Suite) (disc. 2006). The Mozilla foundation is responsible for Firefox (and a few other projects), but Firefox is *not* Mozilla, just as Windows is *not* Microsoft. The UA string itself has [quite the history](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/01/12/history-of-the-user-agent-string/) with it and such silliness has continued .. (so a "non-Mozilla" browser might be caught up as "Mozilla compatible", as was the case of IE11 in GA until the detection rules were updated)

Comment: Is it the Mozilla Compatible Agent? If so, I've heard that it could be a [bings website preview mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15118854/what-is-google-analytics-traffic-from-mozilla-compatible-agent) which causes the js on the website to load.